# SaaS App with AzureADB2C: User Flows for Client SSO?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have a SaaS web app and our clients are requiring SSO authentication for each of them.  We are using AzureADB2C and it works great, but now are looking at adding SSO.

I put in the SSO setup into the B2C tenet and it works great, but really messed up our login screen with a "MyCompanySSO" button to log in with, on our customer-facing login screen.

So now my idea is to have a separate user flow that handles each SSO setup.  Starting with us.  We'd go to MyCompany.OurSaaSApp.us and that'd forward them directly to the user flow endpoint and prompt them to login with their SSO account (AzureAD).

This all seems to try to work, but I'm getting these errors within the AzureADB2C middleware:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler:Warning: .AspNetCore.Correlation. state property not found.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler:Information: Error from RemoteAuthentication: Correlation failed..

Then I get pumped out onto a error page and the login fails.

So 2 things...
1.) Am I going in the right direction knowing what we're wanting to accomplish
2.) What do we need to do to resolve this?

Thanks everyone for the help, it's been greatly appreciated.

(note:)

Just to reiterate.  The SSO works properly when the custom identity provider is attached to the existing SignUpOrIn UserFlow I have configured in the app.  I'm only getting this error when I try to use another UserFlow that I want to use specifically for this SSO.

Comment: Hi PJ. It would seem that Azure AD B2C isn't returning the **state** parameter in the authentication response to your web app. Using the browser developer tools, can you please confirm this is so?

Comment: Could be... Honestly, not even sure what that is...  I have access to the B2C tenet, where could I find that?

Comment: And if that's literally "state" as in state/providence is there a way to decouple that from being a requirement?  Our app will never need that info.  (But no idea if that's what it is. Lol)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about that specific error, although "state" parameter is a parameter that your app sends in the request that will be returned in the token for correlation purposes.

Using and different policy for each federation sounds like the right approach, but if you are doing from a single instance of your app, you'll need to modify the OIDC protocol message with the correct authority (ie policy) on redirect.

In your OIDC middleware configuration, set up a handler for the `RedirectToIdentityProvider` notification.  Then handle it with something like:

```
    private Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
    {
        //var policy = notification.OwinContext.Get<string>("Policy");
        var tenantSegment = notification.Request.Path.Value.Split(new char [] { '/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantSegment) && !tenantSegment.Equals(DefaultPolicy))
        {
            notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = notification.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress.ToLower().Replace(DefaultPolicy.ToLower(), $"B2C_1A_{tenantSegment.ToLower()}_SignUpSignInPolicy");
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

If you need to inject anything else tenant-related, that would be the place to do it.

Comment: Amazing info. I think I see what’s going on here. Might take me a bit to get it flushed out and tested.  Amazing insight though. Could not thank you enough. :). I’ll be back once I get it working.